# auth0.js checkSession() returns a login_required error after logging in with login() from an embedded page

Tags: session, authentication, single-page-application, auth0

I am trying to add ‘keep me logged in’ functionality to my auth0 v9.3.0 authentication flow in my SPA. I have an embedded page at app.domain.io/login where the user enters their credentials. When they hit the sign-in button, the app calls the login() method from auth.js, passing in the username and password. If they checked the box, a permission cookie is set to true.

When the user launches the page later, after the token expires, a router guard calls auth0.js’s checkSession() method to get a new token. At this point, checkSession returns a login_required error even after the user logged in with auth0.js’s login() method. If I instead call the authorize() method and have the user log in on the hosted page, checkSession succeeds and does not return a login_required error.

Why does calling the login() method from the embedded page not fulfill the login_required requirement that authorize() fulfills? I want to get this working without ever redirecting the user to the hosted auth0 page.

Update: 03/28/18

I am currently using auth0 v9.3.0.

Instead of calling the login() method, I am now using axios to make a request to the co/authenticate endpoint. This succeeds and returns a login_ticket, co_id, and co_verifier.

When I call authorize() from auth0.js and pass in the login_ticket as mentioned in the documentation (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jaredhanson/draft-openid-connect-cross-origin-authentication/master/Draft-1.0.txt), I get a ‘No verifier returned from client’ error. I have the co_verifier, but I’m not sure what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [fully working sample](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-single-page-app-login-with-sso-and-api) to follow (SPA using plain JavaScript). The sample illustrates both embedded login and universal login (auth0 hosted login page) approaches.

If you have a codebase on Github and don't mind sharing, then I can take a look for you. Please also update your question to indicate version of auth0.js you are using (or put in comment section below). Do you know (you can check using web browser developer tools) whether you are using `co/authenticate` endpoint when authenticating using auth0.js embedded login? If so, then you would have a Single Sign On session. However, if you are using `oauth/token` endpoint then this would not create a single sign on session. the checkSession() function calls `authorize?prompt=none` under the covers, which detects whether a SSO session is present as part of the authentication process.

Finally, and just for the record, the strong recommendation is to use Auth0 Hosted Login Page (Universal Login). It is a superior approach from security standpoint, and offers other benefits like easy opt-in to services like MFA out of the box. Finally, you could also enable Custom Domains so that your website and the Auth0 Hosted Login Page share the same URL base origin (domain) - end users of your site would not recognise they have been redirected to Auth0 for the authentication. So it is pretty seamless from a UX perspective too.

Comment: Hi arcseldon, thanks for the response! Please find some additional information in the OP. I will work through the example project you provided and see if it shines a light on my problem. If you have any insights in the meantime they would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved by calling auth.crossOriginAuthentication.login() instead of auth.client.login(). auth.crossOriginAuthentication.login() goes through co/authenticate, auth.client.login() goes through oauth/token.